# Filtering items from a protocol buffer

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a piece of system control software that deals with control and status information of hardware devices.  For simplicity, I use a single, moderately complex, protocol buffer structure to communicate between threads.  I also employ the same structure at the network interface so that an external client can control and monitor all parts of the system.

The software may operate using low-bitrate data links, so I'm looking for ways to reduce the network load.  Thus my question:

Without parsing the entire protobuf structure for every I/O operation, is there a way to filter (trim) a protobuf to remove certain messages at runtime?

For example, if I have this `.proto`:

```
message Status {
    optional BusyMsg busy = 10;
    optional FaultMsg system_fault = 11;
    optional VoltageMsg rail_volts = 3000;

    optional InternalStatus internal = 4000;
}

message InternalStatus {
    optional PressureMsg head_pressure = 1;
    optional TempMgs cabinet_temp = 2;
}
```

Is there a simple way to remove (or suppress the transmission of) `rail_volts` or `internal`, possibly by testing for large ID numbers (3000 and 4000, in this case)?  Or is there a good use of extensions and properties that can help?

I understand that I can just call Clear() at the I/O boundary for all fields that I don't want serialized.  But I'd rather mark them, somehow, in the `.proto` rather than relying on the C++ code at the network interface to stay updated.  (The `internal` sub-section is my best idea so far.  I can just snip everything under that.)

I'm not looking for a grind-through-the-structure solution.  I'm wondering if I'm missing an elegant feature of the API.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a reduced Status message, print the full one to a string, and parse it back in as the reduced message.  This would mean you only need to change the proto file and not worry about the C++ API.  (The replication isn't very pretty here.  I don't yet know how to share the protos.)

```
// foo.proto
syntax = "proto2";

message Status1 {
    optional int64 f1 = 1;
    optional int64 f2 = 2;
    optional int64 f3 = 3;
}

message Status2 {
    optional int64 f1 = 1;
    optional int64 f2 = 2;
}


// foo.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "experimental/seanmcl/proto/foo.pb.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  string str;

  {
    Status1 s1;

    s1.set_f1(5);
    s1.set_f2(6);
    s1.set_f3(7);

    s1.SerializeToString(&str);
  }

  {
    Status2 s2;
    s2.ParseFromString(str);

    assert(s2.f1() == 5);
    assert(s2.f2() == 6);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Somewhat better with respect to replication (though not message simplicity) is this:

```
message Status {
    optional StatusRequired status_required = 1;
    optional int64 f3 = 3;
}

message StatusRequired {
    optional int64 f1 = 1;
    optional int64 f2 = 2;
}



{
  Status s3;
  StatusRequired* s4 = s3.mutable_status_required();

  s4->set_f1(5);
  s4->set_f2(6);
  s3.set_f3(7);

  s3.SerializeToString(&str);
}

{
  Status s3;
  s3.ParseFromString(str);
  StatusRequired* s4 (s3.mutable_status_required());

  cout << (s4->f1() == 5) << endl;;
  cout << (s4->f2() == 6) << endl;;
}
```

Which I recognize now is your solution, with the relative importance of fields flipped!